# toggle doesn't work with IE 6

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-6

I have this code which works fine on IE 8 and firefox

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $("#"+divId).toggle(); 
}
 </script>

 </head>

 <body>


 <br />
 <br />

 <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">>> press 2 xxexamplexx</a>
 <div id="myContent" class='hidden'>
 <ul>


 <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent1');"><div><li>xxexamplexx </li></div></a>
 <div id="myContent1" class='hidden'>

 <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent2');">
 <li style="margin-left:7em;">xxexamplexx</li></a>
 <div id="myContent2" class='hidden'>
 <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent3');">
 <li style="margin-left:10em;">xxexamplexx</li></a>
 <div id="myContent3" class='hidden'>
 <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent4');">
 <li style="margin-left:11em;">xxexamplexx</li></a>
 <div id="myContent4" class='hidden'>
 <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent5');">
 <li style="margin-left:14em;">xxexamplexx</li></a>
 <div id="myContent5" class='hidden'>
 <li style="margin-left:16em;"><b>xxexamplexx.</b></li>
 </div>

 </div>

 <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent6');">
 <li style="margin-left:11em;">xxexamplexx</li></a>
 <div id="myContent6" class='hidden'>
 <li style="margin-left:14em;"><b>xxexamplexx</b></li>
 </div>

 </div>

 <div class="space"></div>
 </div><!--content2-->
 </div>
```

when I test it on IE 6, half of the toggles don't work, and they are shown by default, when I first load the page, they will be shown.

any idea how can I fix this?

it doesnt work with IE 7 neither.

Comment: Honestly, just stop supporting IE6 - I did a while back. It'll just make your life miserable. Besides, only 0.6% of users are using IE6 as of last month. And for those 0.6% of the users, your website not working is the least of their problems.

Comment: You can't place anchors and divs inside `<ul>` tags. Read up on web standards.

Comment: You actually have IE 6 installed on your machine? Wow!

Comment: @frenchie, you don't need to install ie6 to test your websites because you can install and use http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Browsers/IETester.shtml

Comment: Telling someone to stop supporting a certain browser isn't very constructive. There are far more users still on IE6 than is reported because of large organizations with locked down workstations all running apps that still use IE6. This is especially true in the financial industry. 75% of our userbase is still IE6 and 7 with IE6 being half of that. In the commercial industry you can't just stop supporting a browser to make it easier on yourself or you lose customers.

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange, I agree with you and as a developer you can't assume that users know the differences between browsers, at least I have to think about ie6 (not often) when I develope something for Bangladeshi (my country) audiences.

Answer (score 0):

You have mess in this code. You should build this this way:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>link</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        no-link
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>link</a>
        <ul>
          ...
        </ul>
      </li>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>link</a>
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then add ids, hrefs and use your function , or better use function like this:

```
$("ul a").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().children("ul").toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will keep all of your divs visible at the first time when page loads those whose id is begining with `myContent`

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('div[id^="myContent"]').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running your code through [the W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). This will tell you about the HTML errors you have.

For instance, you have an `<a>` tag in a `<ul>`, but not in a `<li>`. This is invalid.

The page may render okay in some browsers, but with HTML errors like this, you are likely to find it has issues somewhere along the line. Fix these problems first.